# How to make background gif scalable?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am working on site for skill practice and I have made background which looks cool in fullscreen, but when I scale page, gif is not scaling. As you can see on the screen, background gif save its size when I scale the browser window, but it hasn't supposed to be. I want to make that gif scalable even when I change size of browser window

[image]

Here is vue template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="header">
      <p>Home</p>
      <p>Write-up</p>
      <p>About me and contact</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <img
      src="../assets/video/background.gif"
      alt="back-gif"
      class="background-gif"
    />
    <div class="home-content"></div>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

And here is styles:

```
html body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.header {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  p {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Work Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  p:hover {
    color: green;
    transition: .2s
  }
}
.home-content {
  z-index: 4;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12.5%;
  left: 12.5%;
  height: 45%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.background-gif {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.shadow {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #000000; 
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(Opacity=70);
  position: fixed;
}
```

So, how can I make it scalable?

Comment: You don't have a `background` image, you have an **actual** image.

Comment: you could use it as a "real" background, like this: `.home-content { backgroud: url(../assets/video/background.gif) no-repeat; background-size: cover; }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo not sure if it will work perfectly for you because of relative positioning but this should do, you add height to **auto** or particular **vh**

`img.animated-gif{ width: 100%; height: auto; }`[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hqdn6ac/2/)